# Removing directory contents in node works only on server restart

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got an app written in node and I want to remove single directory contents everytime user hits GET request on homepage ("/"). The problem is that it works ok after initial server start and reaching the homepage, but all consequent tries (like refreshing) don't trigger 'content removal' process (console.log(files) from the example below works fine).

In this case, directory gets empty only after shutting down the node server.

To achieve my goal I'm checking directory content with fs.readdir and if it's there I'm using 'emptyDir' method ( [fs-extra package](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/emptyDir.md)) to delete files.

Code:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('home', { error: req.flash("error") });
  fs.readdir(__dirname + "/assets", function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      if (files.length > 0) {
        console.log(files); //debug
        fs.emptyDir(__dirname + "/assets");
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Thanks for help in advance! Cheers!